# Renaming values in R after binning with cut()

Tags: r

I had a list of numerical values that I wanted to bin using cut(). Now each row has been replaced with the range that it fell into, in the form of ranges using brackets e.g. [0,140] meaning between 0 and 140 inclusive

The problem is these names are lengthy, and eventually require exponent notation, making them even longer, and it makes the graph illegible. Using typeof() it appears it's still in integer form, but I can't figure out how to rename them the way I would with factors. When I tried with factor() and the labels parameter, I was told that sort only worked on atomic lists.

[image: Here's the result of a ggplot2 bar graph. Note the squished labels on the x-axis]

As an example, here's essentially what I tried on my dataset, except with the built-in iris dataset:

```
data(iris)
iris[1] <- cut(iris[[1]], 10, include.lowest=TRUE)
iris[1] <- factor(iris[1], labels = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"))
```

It returns the error:

```
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

Comment: It _is_ a factor. That's what `cut` does: turn a number into a factor. Accordingly, use its `labels` parameter, just like you would with `factor`.

Comment: That's strange, I used typeof() and it told me integer. I tried using the labels parameter with factor but it told me it only worked on atomic lists. Do you know how to overcome this?

Comment: As will any factor, as they're stored as integers. If you call `class` or `is.factor` to see that it's a factor. Beyond that, you need to make [a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) if you want an answer.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't follow the conventions correctly, but could you take a look at the example I've edited into the very bottom of the post? It shows essentially what my steps were except on the iris dataset.

Comment: If you subset with one bracket and one dimension, `iris` will keep its structure as a data.frame instead of dropping to a vector. Use `iris[[1]]`, `iris[ , 1]` or `iris$Sepal.Length` instead.

Comment: Ah I see now, thanks for explaining